# initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast in C warning

Tags: c

On `const char * const str  = ch;` there is a `warning:initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast`.

If I change it to `const char * const str  = (char*)ch` the warning will be `cast to pointer from integer of different size`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    FILE *file1;
    char ch;
    char array[100];

    file1 = fopen("list.txt","r");
    while((ch=fgetc(file1))!=EOF)
        {
            const char * const str  = (char*)ch;
            const char * const delim = "\n";
            char * const dupstr = strdup(str);
            char *saveptr = NULL;
            char *substr = NULL;
            int count = 0;
            printf("original string is %s",dupstr);
            substr = strtok_r(dupstr, delim, &saveptr);
            do{
                printf("#%d filename is %s\n", count++, substr); 
                substr = strtok_r(NULL, delim, &saveptr);
            }
            while(substr);

        free (dupstr);
        return 0;
        }
    fclose(file1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the program?

Comment: Pay attention, that expression `const char * const str  = (char*)ch;` as well as `const char * const str  = ch;` with uninitialized local variable `ch` assign  unknown and WRONG value (address) to pointer `str`

Comment: Your code can work well with char *. Why did you use const char * const?

Answer (score 2):

- `ch=fgetc(file1))!=EOF` is incorrect because ch is a `char`, but `EOF` is an `int`. This is the very reason why `fgetc` and similar functions return an `int`. Easiest way to fix the current code is probably to use a temporary `int`, then copy that to a `char` inside the loop.
- `const char * const str  = (char*)ch;`. Casting from a character to a pointer doesn't make any sense. This is the reason for the warning. If you want to create a temporary string consisting of one character, you should do something like `char str[2] = {ch, '\0'}`. That way you don't have to use `strdup` either.

Answer (score 1):

`ch` is a `char` (an integral type) and you try to convert it to a pointer type `char *` (a type that can store an address). These two types are of very different nature, and it is forbidden by the standard to do such. At least convert the address of `ch` : `(char *)&ch`.

Beware this will not save your code as you are trying to use a `char`  as a C-string. Again these are of different kind. A `char` is just something that let you store the code value of a character. A C-string is a **sequence** of characters terminated by a NUL one.

Suggestions (we don't really know what you try to achieve) : use an array of chars, read a full line from your opened file with `fgets`, etc.